# Solving The Roessler Oscillator using Runge-Kutta algorithm python

Tags: python, numpy, math, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I am having some trouble with this question. I am given this system of equations

```
dx / dt = -y -z
dy / dt = x + a * y
dz / dt = b + z * (x - c)
```

and default values a=0.1, b=0.1, c=14 and also the Runge-Kutta algorithm:

```
def rk4(f, xvinit, Tmax, N):
        T = np.linspace(0,Tmax,N+1)
        xv = np.zeros( (len(T), len(xvinit)) )
        xv[0] = xvinit
        h = Tmax / N
        for i in range(N):
            k1 = f(xv[i])
            k2 = f(xv[i] + h/2.0*k1)
            k3 = f(xv[i] + h/2.0*k2)
            k4 = f(xv[i] + h*k3)
            xv[i+1] = xv[i] + h/6.0 *( k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
        return T, xv
```

I need to solve this system from t=0 to t=100 in time steps of 0.1 and using initial conditions  (0,0,0)=(0,0,0)  at  =0
I'm not really sure where to begin on this, I've tried defining a function to give the Oscillator:

```
def roessler(xyx, a=0.1, b=0.1, c=14):
    xyx=(x,y,x)
    dxdt=-y-z
    dydt=x+a*y
    dzdt=b+z*(x-c)
    return dxdt ,dydt ,dzdt
```

which returns the right side of the equation with default values, i've then tried to solve by replacing f with roessler and filling in values for xvinit,Tmax and N with values i'm given but it's not working.
Any help is appreciated sorry if some of this is formatted wrong i'm new here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you almost got it already. Changing your `roessler` function to the following

```
def roessler(xyx, a=0.1, b=0.1, c=14):
    x, y, z = xyx
    dxdt=-y-z
    dydt=x+a*y
    dzdt=b+z*(x-c)
    return np.array([dxdt, dydt, dzdt])
```

and then calling

```
T, sol = rk4(roessler, np.array([0, 0, 0]), 100, 1000)
```

makes it work.

Taking aside the typo in the first line of your `roessler` function, the key to solving this is to understand that you have a **system** of differential equations, i.e., you need to work with **vectors**. While you already had the input as the vector correct, you also need to make the output of `roessler` a vector and put in the initial value with the appropriate shape.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but i'm not sure what T, sol = rk4(roessler, np.array([0, 0, 0]), 100, 1000) means. I presume sol means solution but i'm not sure how this solves the equation.

Comment: Well, your `rk4` method can be used to solve (autonomous) systems of differential equations, i.e., d/dt y(t) = f(y(t)), note that y(t) can be vector valued. What it needs is a function representing f(y(t)), here `roessler`, an initial value, here `np.array([0, 0, 0]), final time `Tmax = 100` and `N`, the number of steps, which is Tmax/dt, where dt = 0.1, the timestep you specified. If the question is **how** it does that, you need to read up on numerical methods for (ordinary) differential questions